# CISSP exam preparation tips?

Tags: security

I have heard good things about Shon Harris' "All-in-one CISSP".
Anything else?
is an online VTC class any good? : http://www.vtc.com/products/cissp-tutorials.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally went with SANS preparation course. I did it in person at one of their conference but I heard good things about their online course. I must say that their course is very well structured and aimed at giving you the tools required to pass the exam and understand the way (ISC)2 sees security.

I think the first question you should ask yourself is how best you learn and retain new information. Myself I need to be engaged in a live class to retain the maximum from a course and find myself too easily distracted when following online course of doing self-study.

As for the Shon Harris I would say it's a great book. I can also say that it was both recommended by friends who did the CISSP and by the instructor that gave me my CISSP training.  You may want the CISSP CBK as reference material in case you want to dive more in depth into a specific topic. (**do not attempt to use the CBK as a prep guide. As it is likely you'll fall asleep trying to read through it**)

Last advice, before your start studying, test yourself to using the questions from http://www.cccure.org/ to see in which domain you need to work the most.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the questions here - http://www.cccure.org/
seems like a good resource too